# webpack html (ejs) include other templates

Tags: webpack, template-engine, ejs, webpack-dev-server, html-webpack-plugin

So this is my webpack config :

```
import path from 'path';

var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: './dev/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        // publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules"),
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            hash: true,
            template: 'ejs!./dev/index.ejs',
            inject: 'body'
        })
    ]

};
```

My `index.ejs` file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%- include html/one/1.ejs %>

</body>

</html>
```

My folder structure :

```
dev/
  /assets
  /html
    /one
      1.ejs
      1.scss
      1.js
    /two
    /three
  index.js
  index.ejs
```

I want to modularize my html file so I want to include them...

I've tried a lot of methods including another template, but none of them worked...

Can someone give me any ideea of how can I make this work?

Answer (score 5):

Use `ejs-render-loader` package. [see package](https://github.com/tracker1/ejs-render-loader)

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        hash: true,
        template: 'ejs-render!./dev/index.ejs',
        inject: 'body'
    })
]
```

I think it will solve your problem.

update: with webpack3 the syntax for loaders has changed. `'ejs-render!./dev/index.ejs'` should now be: `'ejs-render-loader!./dev/index.ejs'`

Comment: 404 page not found

Answer (score 0):

[ejs-webpack-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs-webpack-loader) works for me (`"ejs-webpack-loader": "^2.2.2", "webpack": "^4.41.5"`). There is a include example ejs at it's web page.

Answer (score -1):

You are using html plugin, make sure if it support ejs and also look for if you are getting any error like if you need to use any öoader for ejs.